# vTiger What should be the best approach, customize Contacts or develop new module?

Tags: vtiger

I’m looking for someone that could give me some tips about the best approach in my vTigerCRM implementation.

I looked at Contacts module and most of fields existing there do not fit my needs.  I know that I can create custom fields, but the amount of custom fields would be greater than 30 fields.

Some existing fields, I would like to change the way that it’s used. For example: in our scenario, the Contact name will be only 1 field. The module has 2 fields: First Name and Last Name.

I could not find a way to disable the First Name field.

Some existing fields on Contacts module would be changed (renaming the labels) using some language file, although this will work for a user perspective, in my developer perspective sounds inappropriate.

I have concerns too about the evolution of vTiger versions. If I change/customize the Contacts module, I think that I’ll have issues when updating/migrating vTiger to newer versions.

The new entity would have most of relationships that Contacts actually has i.e. Activity (monitor mails sent, incoming calls, outgoing calls), Lead conversion, Opportunities, and so on.

I'm really worried about which way to go. If someone could comment this I’ll be grateful.

Answer (score 2):

I'm working on the implementation of vTiger for 3 months now and the first thing I'll tell you is to use the existing modules if possible.

You can modify the type of field you need to custom in vtiger_field by changing the uitype. Most of the time it will be easy, and there is some help on vtiger forums if you need to change a text field into a picklist for example.
Then you can hide the field you don't need by changing displaytype = 0, again in vtiger_field.

I migrated from 5.3 to 5.4 and in the process you provide your old database so this kind of changes are saved. I can't tell you for changes in the php code.

Hope it helps